# Running one function after another completes

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to run loadViews() after the pullData() completes and I am wondering what the best way of doing this is? I would like to set a 10 sec  timeout on it as well so I can display a network error if possible. From what I have read, GCD looks like it is the way to accomplish this but I am confused on the implementation of it. Thanks for any help you can give!

```
//1
pullData()
//2
loadViews()
```

Comment: you should probably simply pass in loadViews as callback / completion block to pullData so that whenever pullData decides it completed pulling it can call it.

Comment: How do I go about doing that? Also can I still implement a timer if I go that route?

Comment: By searching for "swift completion block" for example - your question is generally too broad and will attract primarily opinion-based answers like my comment. You would have to show much more context, explain *exactly* what you want to achieve: a timer or run after it completes are pretty much the opposite of each other. Furthermore you should show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I will look into the completion block. thank you for the suggestion. I was referring to more of a timeout on the block not a timer. Like if pullData() doesn't finish in 10 sec to timeout and display an error.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

What you need is a completion handler with a completion block.

Its really simple to create one:

```
func firstTask(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
    // Do something

    // Call completion, when finished, success or faliure
    completion(success: true)
}
```

And use your completion block like this:

```
firstTask { (success) -> Void in
    if success {
       // do second task if success
       secondTask()
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks great. Thanks for sharing. Would this handle a timeout issue? Is there some sort of built in timeout on completion blocks?

Comment: If there is a timeout, like if you are fetching data from the web, then you just call completion with failure `completion(success: false)`. The completion block wont fire automatically, if not called. But you can still add a timer in your firstTask, to check if there are still no results after xx seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve like this :-

```
func demo(completion: (success: Bool) -> Void) {
     // code goes here
   completion(success: true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I had to init a view once the data is pulled from Parse server. I used the following:

```
func fetchQuestionBank(complete:()->()){

        let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let username = userDefault.valueForKey("user_email") as? String

        var query = PFQuery(className:"QuestionBank")
        query.whereKey("teacher", equalTo: username!)

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    var questionTitle:String?
                    var options:NSArray?

                    for (index, object) in enumerate(objects) {

                        questionTitle = object["question_title"] as? String
                        options = object["options"] as? NSArray
                        var aQuestion = MultipleChoiceQuestion(questionTitle: questionTitle!, options: options!)
                        aQuestion.questionId = object.objectId!
                        InstantlyModel.sharedInstance.questionBank.append(aQuestion)
                    }


                    complete()
                }
            }else{
                println(" Question Bank Error \(error) ")
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is you call the method:

```
self.fetchQuestionBank({ () -> () in
                        //Once all the data pulled from server. Show Teacher View.
                        self.teacherViewController = TeacherViewController(nibName: "TeacherViewController", bundle: nil)
                        self.view.addSubview(self.teacherViewController!.view)
                    })
```

Answer (score -4):

```
  function1();
  function2();
```

**Use functions!!** Once function1() function completed, function2() will execute.