# swift completion block does not execute tasks in order?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

Sorry newbie here. I tried to follow [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357807/running-one-function-after-another-completes) but I failed. My guess is `completion(true)` was run before the database finished fetching the data? Any idea how to fix this?

viewDidLoad code:

```
getInfoFromDatabase{ (success) -> Void in
        if success {
            loadInfoOntoUI()
        }
    }
```

getInfoFromDatabase function:

```
func getInfoFromDatabase(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
     self.caption = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Caption"] as! String
     self.views = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Views"] as! Int
     self.votes = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Votes"] as! Int

     print(self.views)
     print(self.votes)
     print(self.caption)
    // these variables get printed correctly in console
    })

    completion(true)
}
```

loadInfoOntoUI function:

```
func loadInfoOntoUI() {
    captionText.text = self.caption
    print(self.caption) // But when I added a breakpoint here, the console says text is nil
    viewText.text = String(views)
    voteText.text = String(votes)
}
```

Thanks lots!

Comment: Are you setting `UIKit` properties on the main thread?

Comment: completion is likely called before the async stuff has completed.

Comment: in `getInfoFromDatabase` method, You are making a database request which is asynchronous. So you need to call your completion in the asynchonus method's completion.

Comment: Yep I've imported UIKit. I can set the captionText to other things using captionText.text = "random String" in view did load, so i think the textview is connected properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the completion inside the observe block...

```
func getInfoFromDatabase(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
     self.caption = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Caption"] as! String
     self.views = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Views"] as! Int
     self.votes = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Votes"] as! Int

     print(self.views)
     print(self.votes)
     print(self.caption)
     // these variables get printed correctly in console
     completion(true)
     })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
completion(true)
```

should be in completion of the running task to get it to return after the data is fetched  , correct to this

```
 func getInfoFromDatabase(completion: (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
     self.caption = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Caption"] as! String
     self.views = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Views"] as! Int
     self.votes = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["Votes"] as! Int

     print(self.views)
     print(self.votes)
     print(self.caption)
    // these variables get printed correctly in console
      completion(true)
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are completely bypassing the point of the completion handler by placing it outside of the async block.

```
stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in }
```

Is an async function which takes some time to complete. You use the completion handler to tell you when it is complete so you need to call it within the async completion handler.

```
stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in 
    // do stuff

    completion(true)
}
```

What is happening in your code...

```
stoRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in // this gets called 1st
    // do stuff
    // this 3rd
}

completion(true) // this 2nd
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use completion blocks like that. Your code also might create retain cycles (reaching UI elements from action blocks is not safe without using `weak self`).
Consider using any asynchronous task library like `PromiseKit` or `BoltsSwift`:

https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit

https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Swift