# swift: call action after implementing another action

Tags: ios, swift

I have two actions.

I want to first action will be implemented and after that second action will be call. If I add action like this:

```
func actions {
    action1()
    action2()
}
```

but in my code and action implemented at same time.

I have this code in first action:

```
let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

pageController.dataSource = self
pageController.delegate = self

firstPage = 0
secondPage = 1

guard let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: firstPage) else { return }
guard let secondController = getContentViewController(withIndex: secondPage) else { return }

pageViewController?.setViewControllers([firstController, secondController], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It is a flip animation.

If I use this

```
func actions {
    action1()
    action2()
}
```

My flip animation will not be able to show.

Maybe I need to use timer?

Comment: you should call action2() in the completion of action1()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running one function after another completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357807/running-one-function-after-another-completes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include callbacks on each function in such once functional operations are completed they invoke the other functions. eg:

Create a callback function

```
func action1(complete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) {
    // animation operation 

    // Notify callback 
    complete(true)
}
```

How to use callback functions

```
action1(complete: { (animationCompleted)
   if animationCompleted {
     // Invoke second animation function 
     // Remember use `self` instance once your inside a callback method
     self.action2() 
   }
})
```

Comment: My animation flip animation not showing. I need time to show animation and after that call another action.