# How to check if function finished?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a function that requests data from an API and puts it in a global struct, so I can read that data from anywhere in the application, all other functions and classes are mainly working in this data. I want to check if that function has finished loading the data before running the other class functions.

The other functions are in different classes.

I cannot use a completion handler (completion: @escaping(_ success: Bool) -> Void) . as this will trigger that function every time it's called, thus it will lead to the data being downloaded over and over again.

Instead, I'm looking for a way to check if that function has completed it's download tasks, then continue with the other functions.

This has to be dynamic, since if let's say, the internet on the device was not working, and then the user connects to the internet, that function will need to run again to try to get the data (could use a refresh button) and notify other classes and function that it finished again so the other functions can start loading the data into the variables

```
import Foundation 
import Alamofire 
import SwiftyJSON

struct GlobalUser {
    static var json : JSON!
     }


func getData()  {

    // set api url
    let LOCATIONAPI_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/0123456789abcdef9876543210fedcba/42.3601,-71.0589"

    // request JSON from url, using Alamofire Library

    Alamofire.request(LOCATIONAPI_URL).responseJSON { (response) in

        print("data requested")

        let result = response.result


        // check if respose is valid

        if result.isSuccess{

         GlobalUser.json = JSON(result.value!)    

     }

}

}
```

Comment: If you have one place where you need to access the data, then you can fetch the data there and use a completion handler.  If there are multiple places or the logic is otherwise loosely coupled then you can post a `Notification` when the data has been fetched.  Interested objects can subscribe to that notification.

Comment: Also, I would suggest that you make `GlobalUser.json` a normal optional, not an implicitly unwrapped optional - that way you can easily safely check whether the data has been retrieved.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you so much, using `Notification` was exactly what I needed! I have also changed GlobalUser.json to a normal optional so I can check if the variable is nil or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometime ago I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357807/running-one-function-after-another-completes).
The idea is to have a completionHandler, that return

```
func yourFonction(_ parameters: [String: String], completionHandler: (_ result: [String: Any], _ error: Error) -> Void){
     //Your Code
     completionHandler(result, error)
}
```

look [here (Tutorial)](https://medium.com/@nimjea/completion-handler-in-swift-4-2-671f12d33178), [here](https://grokswift.com/completion-handlers-in-swift/) et even [there (Swift Closures Doc)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) for more information

Comment: Hi Thanks for your help, the only problem with this solution I think that I would need to call the function every single time I'm trying to use my global variables? If that's the case, this will cause to the data being downloaded over and over again, is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Well, according to your question, this is definitely an answer - an appropriate answer at that. Are you calling the `getData()` function over and over? We don't see that. Please post all the code necessary to answer your question

Comment: @impression7vx , Thanks for your help, please read the question I have specified that using the above solution the getData() function will be called over and over. Thank you

Comment: Yes, but why? Put it on a timer - if it gets called - invalidate the timer and the function won't get called anymore... or asynchronously, either way, same concept